# Set of Power of a complex set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say $K = \{(2,1),(2,3),(2,5),(4,1),(4,3),(4,5)\}$
what is the power of set of $K$, I know since it got 6 elements the cardinality should be 64. However, I can't seem to find the proper power of set, always finding around 38 elements.

Edit: I got the result of $K$ by a cartesian product $A\times B$.

Comment: If you think of $K$ as an ordered list, one way to think of it is as corresponding with six-character bit strings, 011001 etc, with 0 or 1 representing whether each member of the list is absent from the subset or present in the subset. You can write out the subsets instead of bit strings but that is the fundamental idea. e.g. 010001 corresponds to the subset {(2,3), (4,5)}. 000000 is the empty set. 111111 is $K$.

Comment: @Dom What kind of answer are you looking for?  Do you really expect someone to type out all $64$ subsets?

Comment: @AlexKruckman [Apparently ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4021257/28111)

Comment: I did it as a joke and because $\mathcal{P}(K)$ is sort of borderline and the answer may actually help the OP :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed the powerset $\mathcal{P}(K)$ contains $64$ elements. Here is the complete list:

$$
\mathcal{P}(K) = \{
\emptyset,
\{(2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3)\},
\{(2, 5)\},
\{(4, 1)\},
\{(4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5)\}, \\
\{(2, 3), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5)\},
\{(2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5)\},
\{(4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(4, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 5), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 3)\},
\{(2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3)\},
\{(4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1), (4, 3)\}, 
\{(2, 1), (4, 3), (2, 3), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 1), (4, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5)\},
\{(2, 1), (4, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(2, 1), (4, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
\{(4, 3), (2, 3), (4, 5), (2, 5), (4, 1)\},
K
\}.
$$

Perhaps, it is helpful in finding out what elements were missing from your list of $38$.